# Does the message "Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master " always get displayed?

Tags: git, rebase

I worked on master branch and tried this `git rebase -i HEAD~3`. I actually tried to delete a commit from commit history, but realized there was no need for that.

After the nano editor opened I made no changes to the file and closed it without saving. However a message was displayed in the command line stating:
"Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master ". What does that mean? I didn´t (as far as I know) do any changes. When I looked at git log and git status I saw no changes.

Afterwards I made a couple of commits and pushed them to the remote.

My question is: Why was the message displayed? Did anything actually change?

I am asking this because this is actually a shared project and I was about to do a major mistake with rebasing something and now I am worried that I might´ve done so. As you can probably tell I am quite a n00b with git :)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your particular case, nothing actually happened.  The rebase succeeded—and did a modest amount of work in the process—but everything it did resulted in *exactly the original commits*.  Hence the last part, when it said `updated refs/heads/master`, means: *I changed the name `master` from identifying commit X to identifying commit X* (for some hash ID *X*).  Essentially, it erased the old entry and replaced it with an absolutely, totally, 100% identical entry.

#### What's going on here (if you care)

The *reason* for all this is a bit complicated.  What `git rebase` does, in essence, is to *copy* commits.  The issue here is that a commit, once made, is frozen in time: no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.  If we made a commit that's bad, or even just "not so great", we might want to *replace* it with a new and improved one: we might want to extract the original into a work-area, make some changes to the work-area, and make a new commit that's mostly the same, but ever so slightly different.

If we do this—if we make a copy of the commit with some part(s) changed—we get a new and different commit with a new and different hash ID.  And that leads to a conundrum, because Git branch names only remember *one* hash ID.  Specifically, a branch name remembers the hash ID of the *last* commit that we want to call part of the branch.

Each commit, meanwhile, *also* remembers a hash ID.  More precisely, each commit remembers zero or more hash IDs, but usually exactly one.  The usual hash ID that a commit remembers is the hash ID of the commit that comes *before* this particular commit.  Git calls that the *parent* of the commit.

Note that when a child commit is "born" (created), Git knows the hash ID of the parent of the child (or, for merge commits, parents, plural).  So Git can stuff that hash ID *into* the child during the creation.  But once the child is written out, it's frozen for all time.  So, when that child itself becomes a parent later, it can't have its children added to it.  It can only keep remembering its parent(s).

But that's good enough!  If we draw this situation, we find that commits make a nice simple backwards-looking chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit.  Commit `H` is the child-most; its parent is `G`; and `H` remembers `G`'s ID.  Commit `G` remembers `F`'s ID, and `F` remembers another parent, and so on, all the way back to the beginning of the repository.

A *branch name* like `master` therefore only has to remember the ID of the *last* commit, in this case `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

To add a new commit, we have Git extract the latest `master` one, i.e., `H`, into a work-area.  We then work on it and prepare a new commit.  Once it's all ready (with `git add` and so on), we run `git commit`.  Git now freezes everything we've told it to save for the new commit, adds the actual hash ID of `H`, and writes out a new commit—which gets a new, unique, big ugly hash ID that we'll just call `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

The *last* step is that `git commit` writes this new hash ID into the name `master`, so that `master` now remembers commit `I` instead of commit `H`.  That's OK, because commit `I` itself remembers commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

If we decide that we flubbed commit `I`, we can't actually *change* `I` at all, but we can *copy* it to a new and improved replacement, perhaps one called `J`:

```
             J
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

If we now force Git to make the name `master` remember `J`'s hash ID, it *looks like* we somehow magically changed `I`, as long as we don't pay any attention to the hash IDs.  (Git, by contrast, pays *very strict* attention to hash IDs.  Hash IDs are sort of its life-blood: they are how almost everything inside Git works.)

With some kinds of rebase, we want to copy a series of commits so that they come at a different place in a chain:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- feature
```

Here, if we want our feature to build on commit `H` instead of commit `F`, we'll have to re-copy `I` and `J` to make them come after `H`, and probably use slightly different source code too, and then we'll have Git rip the name `feature` off of `J` and make it point to the new copies:

```
             I'-J'  <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J   [abandoned]
```

In other cases, we just want to make some little fix.  For instance, we start with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

but decide we want to change the log message (`reword` in `git rebase -i`).  That will make a new and improved `I'` as before.  If all we are doing is `reword`, well, `J` *was* fine, but `J`'s parent is `I`, so we need a new and improved `J'` whose parent is the copy `I'`:

```
             I'-J'  <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   [abandoned]
```

The clever part of `git rebase` is that, unless you tell it not to—using `--force` for instance—it will notice a case where there's actually *no change at all* to commit `I`, and just re-use the original commit `I`.  That happens if:

- there's no change to any of the source;
- there's no change to the author name, log message, and so on; and
- there's no change to the parent hash ID.

That was the case for your rebase: you said *don't make any changes to anything* and the parent hash IDs were also the same, so Git just left all three commits in place, having carefully determined that this was OK to do.<sup>1</sup>

Then, as Git always does after completing a rebase operation, Git stuffed the last-copied-commit's hash ID into the branch name, so that the name records the last commit in the branch.  That was the `updated` part.

---

<sup>1</sup>Because of the `--force` option, `git rebase` really does check for this.  If you've told rebase that it absolutely *must* replace the commits, it will make a trivial change—update the author date, for instance—so that the new commit has a new and different hash ID.

The `git filter-branch` command, which is otherwise like `git rebase` on steroids—it copies major swaths of commits while making arbitrary changes to them based on filter arguments—*doesn't* do any such checks.  It relies instead of the fact that if you make an absolutely, totally, 100% bit-for-bit identical commit that matches some previous existing commit, you actually wind up getting the *original hash ID back* and not storing a new object in the database.  If `git rebase` did not have `--force`, it would probably just do that, rather than checking.  With `git filter-branch`, if you want to force a copy, you're supposed to arrange for that in one of your filters.

Note that the 100%-match requirement means that the new commit must have:

- the same source tree
- the same author and committer names and dates/times
- the same log message, including the exact spelling of every character (including white space) and same encoding (UTF-8 or whatever)
- the same *parent* hash IDs, i.e., the same history leading up to that commit

and if the commit matches that closely, well, it *is* the original commit, rather than an altered copy.  So it's correct for Git to re-use the original here.